# How to change vectors from SU(2) to SO(3)?

Tags: quantum-state, bloch-sphere

I know how to change the special unitary matrix in $SU(2)$ to the matrix in $SO(3)$, and I found one way to change the state(vector) from $2\times 1$ to $3\times 1$, but I don't know why.

The method is shown below:

For any vector$|\psi\rangle \equiv (a+bi,c+di)^T$, the corresponding one is
$$\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\begin{pmatrix} 
2(ac + bd) \\ 
2(-bc + ad)\\
a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$
The process is :$\langle\psi|\vec{\sigma} |\psi\rangle$, and the $x$ component of it is the first line in $(1)$, the $y$ component of it is the second line in $(1)$ and so on, where $\sigma $ stands for Pauli operator

$$\sigma _x = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\sigma _y = \begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{pmatrix}, \sigma _z=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

For example, if the $2\times 1$ vector is $\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta/2)\\ \sin(\theta /2)e^{i\phi}\end{pmatrix}$ then using transformation $(1)$ the corresponding $3\times 1$ vector is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\\ \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\ \cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}.
$$

However, I don't understand how to prove (1).

---

***[Cross-posted on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/606545/58382)***

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/606545.

Comment: I think it's two communities, so I post this question in two places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

You have rediscovered the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere)! :-)

### Interesting special cases

Before we prove that the map defined by equation $(1)$ is the representation of single-qubit quantum states as points on the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere), it is instructive to consider a few special cases. Let us denote the map with $\phi: \mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is the Hilbert space of a qubit. We calculate that

$$
\phi(|0\rangle) = \phi\left(\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}
2 \cdot (1 \cdot 0 + 0 \cdot 0) \\
2 \cdot (-0 \cdot 0 + 1 \cdot 0) \\
1^2 + 0^2 - 0^2 - 0^2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix} \\
\phi(|1\rangle) = \phi\left(\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}
2 \cdot (0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot 0) \\
2 \cdot (-0 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot 0) \\
0^2 + 0^2 - 1^2 - 0^2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\-1 \end{pmatrix} \\
\phi(|+\rangle) = \phi\left(\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}
2 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + 0 \cdot 0\right) \\
2 \cdot \left(-0 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot 0\right) \\
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + 0^2 - \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 - 0^2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix} \\
\phi(|-\rangle) = \phi\left(\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}
2 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + 0 \cdot 0\right) \\
2 \cdot \left(-0 \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot 0\right) \\
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + 0^2 - \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 - 0^2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix} \\
\phi(|{+i}\rangle) = \phi\left(\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}
2 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot 0 + 0 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \\
2 \cdot \left(-0 \cdot 0 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \\
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + 0^2 - 0^2 - \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix} \\
\phi(|{-i}\rangle) = \phi\left(\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}
2 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot 0 + 0 \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right) \\
2 \cdot \left(-0 \cdot 0 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right) \\
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + 0^2 - 0^2 - \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Though not a proof, the above equalities are very suggestive.

Moreover, these equalities explain why the three components of $\langle\psi|\vec{\sigma}|\psi\rangle$ correspond to the three components of $\phi(|\psi\rangle)$. For example, $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ are eigenvectors of $\sigma_x$, so $\phi$ maps them to vectors that are fixed by the corresponding 3D rotation of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

### Proof in the general case

You have almost obtained the proof in the general case when you switched from representing an arbitrary quantum state as $|\psi\rangle=(a + bi, c + di)^T$ to representing it as $|\psi\rangle=(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}, e^{i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2})$ and calculated that

$$
\begin{align}
\phi(|\psi\rangle) &= \phi\left(\begin{pmatrix}\cos\frac{\theta}{2} \\ e^{i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\end{pmatrix}\right) \\
& =\begin{pmatrix}
2 \cos\frac{\theta}{2} \sin\frac{\theta}{2} \cos\phi \\
2 \cos\frac{\theta}{2} \sin\frac{\theta}{2} \sin\phi\\
\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2} - \sin^2\frac{\theta}{2} \cos^2\phi - \sin^2\frac{\theta}{2} \sin^2\phi
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
\sin\theta\cos\phi \\
\sin\theta\sin\phi \\
\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
$$

Now the only missing step is to notice that the last result is the point on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with azimutal angle $\phi$ and polar angle $\frac{\theta}{2}$, exactly as on the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere#Definition).

### Relationship to the Lie group homomorphism $SU(2)\to SO(3)$

A key property of the Bloch sphere is that for any unitary $U \in SU(2)$ and any state $|\psi\rangle \in \mathcal{H}$, the 3-vector $\phi(U|\psi\rangle)$ can be obtained from the 3-vector $\phi(|\psi\rangle)$ by rotating the latter using $\Phi(U)\in SO(3)$ where $\Phi: SU(2) \to SO(3)$ denotes the Lie group homomorphism that maps single-qubit unitaries in $SU(2)$ to 3D rotations in $SO(3)$.

This fact can be expressed as

$$
\phi(U|\psi\rangle) = \Phi(U)\phi(|\psi\rangle)\tag2
$$

or by saying that the following diagram

$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
&\mathcal{H}      & \xrightarrow{\phi}   & S^2             & \\
U&\Bigg\downarrow &                      & \Bigg\downarrow & \Phi(U) \\
&\mathcal{H}      & \xrightarrow[\phi]{} & S^2             & \\
\end{array}
$$

commutes for every $U\in SU(2)$. The proof of $(2)$ is a straightforward, but somewhat lengthy calculation.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few different ways to interpret the question.
For starters, it is worth noting that the titular question cannot be interpreted at face value: $\mathbf{SU}(2)$ and $\mathbf{SO}(3)$ are *not* vector spaces, and thus their elements are not vectors. Rather, they are (among other things) *groups*, and more specifically *[Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group)*.

Nonetheless, these groups can indeed be made to act on vector spaces.
In particular, they admit "natural" representations of the form
$$\phi_{\mathbf{SU}(2)}:\mathbf{SU}(2)\to\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb C),
\\
\phi_{\mathbf{SO}(3)}:\mathbf{SO}(3)\to\operatorname{GL}(3,\mathbb R).$$
Here $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb F)$ denotes the group of invertible $n\times n$ matrices over a field $\mathbb F$.
One also often *defines* these Lie groups as *matrix groups*, that is, presenting their elements directly as $2\times2$ special unitary and $3\times 3$ special orthogonal matrices. In which case, this paragraph can be safely ignored for our purposes.

These two groups are also tightly related: there is a (surjective) *homomorphism* $\phi:\mathbf{SU}(2)\to\mathbf{SO}(3)$, whose kernel is $\{\pm I\}\subset\mathbf{SU}(2)$. A nice way to define it is via the Lie algebras, as
$$\phi\left(\exp\Big(\sum_{i=1}^3 c_i t_i\Big)\right) \equiv
\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^3 c_i J_i\right),$$
where $c_i\in\mathbb R$, and $t_i\in\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and $J_i\in\mathfrak{so}(3)$ denote basis elements for the Lie algebras.
This homomorphism is thus not injective, but rather is "*two-to-one*". An easy way to verify this directly is computing $\exp[\alpha(-\frac{i}{2}\sigma_x)]$ and the corresponding image through $\phi$, which is $\exp(\alpha J_x)$. Note that here $-\frac{i}{2}\sigma_x\equiv t_x$ is a basis element of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, and $J_x\equiv |3\rangle\!\langle2|-|2\rangle\!\langle3|$ is the corresponding basis element of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$.

So with this in mind, how should the question be interpreted? I'd say the point is whether $\phi$ can be leveraged to find some $f:\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb R^3$ which connects the spaces on which the two groups are represented, that is, one such that
$$f(U\psi)=\phi(U)f(\psi),$$
for all $U\in\mathbf{SU}(2)$ and $\psi\in\mathbb C^2$.
Note that, because $\phi$ is not injective, $f$ will probably also not be: the RHS won't change upon changing $U\to -U$, but the LHS might change, unless $f$ is chosen appropriately.

To make this more concrete, consider unitaries of the form $U=e^{\theta t_z}$, where $t_z\equiv -i\sigma_z/2$. Then,
$$\psi\equiv\begin{pmatrix}\psi_0 \\\psi_1\end{pmatrix}
\mapsto U\psi =
\begin{pmatrix}e^{-i\theta/2}\psi_0 \\e^{i\theta/2}\psi_1\end{pmatrix}
= e^{-i\theta/2}\begin{pmatrix}\psi_0 \\e^{i\theta}\psi_1\end{pmatrix}.$$
On the other hand, $\phi(U)=e^{\theta J_z}$, and thus
$$
\phi(U)f(\psi)
=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}f_1(\psi)\\ f_2(\psi) \\ f_3(\psi)\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}c_\theta f_1-s_\theta f_2\\ s_\theta f_1+c_\theta f_2 \\ f_3\end{pmatrix},
$$
with some shorthand notation in the last equation.

I'm not completely sure what's an *a priori* way to get to the explicit form of $f$, but one can readily observe that the [Hopf map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration) does the job. This is the map defined as
$$f(\psi) = \begin{pmatrix}2\Re(\bar\psi_0 \psi_1) \\ 2\Im(\bar\psi_0 \psi_1) \\ |\psi_0|^2 - |\psi_1|^2\end{pmatrix}.
$$